# Saving with mods

Tags: civilization-5, mods

Please tell me how to view the full list of mods in the save. Since when you open the window with the download of the save, and click to see which mods are needed to download the save, the list appears, but not the whole one. Maybe there are some files where you can see which mods were used in this creation. tell me if anyone has encountered this)